# font awesome not working

Tags: fonts, font-awesome

Created this simple html using notepad referencing to font awesome cdn. Doesn't work please advise.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>


    <body>
    <i class"fa-television"></i>
    television


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work: `<i class="fa fa-television"></i>`. You should add in this way **fa fa-name**.
For icons go to [Font Awesome Icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

And change your link to `href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"`

Comment: The link you were using did not work, I tried your code with different link, then it worked

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>


<body>
  <i class="fa fa-tv" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  television


</body>

</html>
```

`=` is missing after `class` in the line `<i class"fa-television"></i>`

Replace that line with `<i class="fa fa-television"></i>`. The problem is with the version. Television icon was introduced after version 4.4.0, but you're using version 4.1.0.

Comment: Updated my answer!